# Ошибка "Use of undeclared identifier 'size'"

Tags: c++, массивы, xcode

Вроде всё правильно написал, но пишет мол

> Use of undeclared identifier 'size'

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a [30];
    for (int i = 0; i < size(a); i++) {
        cout << i << "Число"<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что нужно подключить соответствующий файл - список см. [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), ну и компилятор должен поддерживать C++17.

Это если вы хотите получить количество элементов. Если размер в байтах - надо `sizeof(a)`.

Если компилятор этот стандарт не тянет - можно использовать `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`.

Comment: нет мне нужно именно size() главное все работает в Visual Studio... а Xcode даже с примерами что вы скинули не может запустить... может ли быть что у Xcode старый компилятор? как проверить какой версии компилятор?

Comment: Откровенно говоря, надежного способа, кроме как прочесть документацию :), не подскажу. Теоретически должно давать информацию значение макроса `__cplusplus`, но это чисто теоретически. В командной строке соответствующего ключика нет? Кстати, а что за компилятор? Gnu?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288230/how-do-i-enable-c17-in-xcode-for-mac-osx

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, я сделал как было в ответе на тот вопрос. поменял с++14 который стоял по дефолту на с++17.